# Running Callgrind on simple R file

Tags: r, profiling, valgrind, callgrind

I want to use Callgrind to find bottlenecks in some complicated Rcpp code. Since I couldn't get it to work, I decided to write a simple R file instead, to make sure it was doing what it should.

However, I still can't get it to work.

My simple function is:

```
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly=T)
test_callgrind <- function(args) {
  x <- args[1]
  a <- 0
  for (i in 1:x) {
    a <- i
  }
  return(a)
}
a <- test_callgrind(args)
save(a, file="a.rdata")
```

I then type:

```
valgrind --tool=callgrind Rscript filename.R 1000
```

This seems to run fine, and produces callgrind.out.XYZ, as the [documentation](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html) says it should.

I then type:

```
callgrind_annotate callgrind.out.XYZ
```

and get the following:

```
Use of uninitialized value $events in string ne at /usr/bin/callgrind_annotate line 446.
Line 0: missing events line
```

This is exactly the same error as I got with my more complicated code, so something besides the function is at fault.

Does anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong please? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

May be a bit too late, but what if you instead use

```
R -d "valgrind --tool=callgrind" -f filename.R
```